# Best design for allowing custom attributes against an entity

Tags: c#, wpf, nhibernate

I am relatively new to C# and WPF and am embarking on creating a Stock Management system. The system will have customers, all with varying needs of storing there stock.

Stock will be stored in a table with columns such as ProductId, CustomerId, BookQty, OnHandQty, OnOrderQty etc. Each customer will want to have different attributes stored against there product, such as Lot Number, Used By Date, Product Date etc. I want to make this as dynamic as possible so that when setting the customer up, we define how they want to manage there stock.

My question is, what is the best design from a database point of view of storing these attributes against stock?

- Have separate fields in the stock table such as `TagString1, TagString2, TagString3, TagDate1, TagDate2, TagDate3, TagInt1, TagIn2, TagInt3`
- Have single fields and just do a cast for non string values, such as `Tag1, Tag2, Tag3` (and have a lookup table to define what data types exist in which column as well as the column header)
- Store these in a separate table all together?
- XML data type?
- Key/Pair value table
- Dynamically change table structure (thinking this is a bad idea, throwing the idea out there though)

I've seen previous systems use 1 and 2. I'm thinking 2 is probably the simplest to implement, but the idea of XML fields is growing on me.

Can anyone shed some light on the advantages/disadvantages of such the above?

The solution needs to be indexable (is that a word?) with performance being of concern. Most of the querying of data will be down through NHibernate so I'm not extremely worried about complexity of quering through raw SQL.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty common scenario and in *real* world you will see all solutions you mentioned (sigh). Let me assume it's not a toy application then you will have (or some customers may have) many custom *attributes* and you will also need to perform *real* work around them (queries, updates and so on).

> Have separate fields in the stock table...

It's easiest solution to begin with (and this is the only benefit it has together with good performance). However it has many drawbacks:

- It's a pain to maintain, when you will run out of *free* columns then you will need to change database schema.
- If you need a *new* column type (for example for geographical location of warehouse where a product is stored) then you will need to add more columns.
- It doesn't explain itself. When you see `TagInt1` in a query you don't understand what it contains, this is error prone for query writing and debugging. Do not under stimate this aspect: you may save few days of developing but you will pay them each time you customize an installation.
- If each customer has its own use for that columns then you can't write generic utilities (for example migrations, updates and import/export). For each customer they need to be customized (again something you'll pay during installation).
- It wastes DB resources (but they *may* be little enough to be ignored, DB engines are pretty good to optimize disk space for null fields).
- Your source code will have more *configuration points*, for example to build queries you need to read a mapping table to convert "Lot Code" (what user sees in UI) to `TagString1` (what you write in queries). You also need to perform type checking (to validate user input) then mapping table also has to contain column type. More code to write, more code to test, more bugs to fix.

I wouldn't use this unless you have just one (or two) columns with an almost fixed set of meanings. What you save in development you will pay 10X in setup and support.

> Have single fields and just do a cast...

All the above with even harder debugger and weaker type checking. You're more *free* because you don't have to *guess* types you may need but you need to pay a high price for this.

> XML data type?

It's half way a nice idea, data is structured, there are tools to analyze and to validate them and your DB schema is *clean*. Keep in mind that these things will be harder:

- Some DB engines have some support for XML columns but queries will be harder to write and to understand.
- As for your first solution code will be harder to write because some data will stay in *plain* columns and some data in XML. User shouldn't see any difference then you have to hide this implementation detail, easier for them but harder for you.
- Import and export of data. Because of its *double nature* your tools need to handle things described in two ways. You may use usual tools for SQL but they need to smoothly integrate with XML tools for *custom attributes* (and again user shouldn't see any difference).

Moreover don't forget that XML will impact performance (because of query syntax, its verbosity and because it's less friendly for DB indices - some engines don't even support them). NHibernate supports (it lets you use XQuery, don't think about a built-in support...) them but syntax is ugly and complex (but this is only my POV).

I wouldn't use this unless nothing else is applicable (or you have to manage legacy XML data you can't convert on-the-fly).

> Dynamically change table structure...

It's not a bad idea, at least in my opinion. During installation you create a *description* of your database using - let's say - a visual tool. Another tool will then generate DB schema and configure everything with per-site values.

Performance will be great, tables will be indices friendly and each user will have its own schema (if you're using Team Foundation Server think about, even if it's not the same, its configurability for bugs/tasks and so on). It won't suffer for issues mentioned before in other solutions and it's best one to give each customer maximum flexibility.

What are drawbacks of this? It's a huge task. To do a decent job you will need to make your code extremely flexible. You should do very few assumptions (in code) and everything has to be configured. Moreover you have to write all tools you will need (designer for configuration and configuration generator).

It may be done in steps (one fixed part, 99% of your application) and one configurable part (1%) but you will still need tools (otherwise, again, you will pay 10X during deployment what you save in development).

Also note that tools have to be flexible enough to update something *unknown* (for example when you release a new utility/feature) and they have to handle updates (when you update DB schema in a newer version).

For me it's best solution but only if you have resources to invest on it, an half done job will call for pain.

> Store these in a separate table all together?
>
> Key/Pair value table

Let me discuss them together. It's the solution I saw more often and it works pretty well.

These *attributes* must stay in a separate table where they're stored as key/value pairs. To do it you need to *simulate* a variant type, something like this:

```
Id | KeyId | ValueInt | ValueString | ValueBit
----------------------------------------------
```

Note that it's not the only way to simulate a *variant* then check your DB engine documentation to see what it offers (for example Microsoft SQL Server 2014 introduced a `sql_variant` type), if you have DB engine support then use it.

How this differs from first and second solution you mentioned? Everything is inside DB. Let's imagine you have attributes for a `Product` table. You will store them in a table named `ProductAttribute` (suppose with `Id`, `ProductId`, `KeyId` and `Value` columns). You'll *describe* them in a table named `ProductAttributeMetadata` where Id columns links to `KeyId` in `ProductAttribute`:

```
Id | Name | Type
----------------
```

What's advantage of this? Everything can be done in SQL, for example to query all attributes you just need to write:

```
SELECT
  M.Name, A.Value
FROM
  ProductAttribute AS A
INNER JOIN
 ProductAttributeMetadata AS M ON M.Id = A.KeyId
WHERE
 M.ProductId = @ProductId
```

Also your user interface has not to know about these details and they can populate columns with *blind* queries. This technique becomes powerful when you need more. Imagine you need to display that columns in a specific order: just add a `DisplayOrder` column in your `ProductAttributeMetadata` table. Imagine you need to restrict input to a fixed set of values, you have a `Type` column you can use for this: let's introduce a `List` type and add a new table `ProductAttributeMetadataValueList`:

```
Id, KeyId, DisplayOrder, DisplayName, DbValue
---------------------------------------------
```

You need to group values? Just add a `Group` column. When code is written then UI will be unaware of any customization.

Drawbacks? Of course it has.

- You don't need to write much code to support this technique but it's harder to test than - let's say - your first solution.
- Queries may be hard to write (because you will need more `JOIN`s) and for complex queries you may even need a tool (but much better than your first and second solutions).
- Performance won't be as good as you may wish if you need to query attributes often (because of `JOIN`s).

However it has some nice benefits:

- It's incredibly flexible (2nd only to *dynamically* change DB schema).
- It needs more code than other solutions (but less than solution with *dynamic* change of DB schema) and it's not too hard to test.
- Import, export and merge and updates will be easier than any other solution.

> Anything else?

If so far you didn't consider them I think you should take a look to No-SQL databases. Some of them are inherently schema-less (I know I oversimplify) and you may have some nice ideas from them.

### Conclusions

I try to summarize a little bit. If you want to keep queries readable then I'd go with (partially) *dynamically* generated DB schema. You will need to write tools and tons of tests but it has best performance and it's only solution that keep your queries readable. Compare these fake (untested/unoptimized/ugly) examples:

```
-- Tags
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Product
WHERE
  TagString3 LIKE '001-000-A%'

-- Dynamic
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Product
WHERE
  LotCode LIKE '001-000-A%'

-- Key/Value
SELECT
  P.*
FROM
  Product AS P
INNER JOIN
  ProductAttribute AS A ON P.Id = A.ProductId
INNER JOIN
 ProductAttributeMetadata AS M ON A.KeyId = M.Id
WHERE
  M.Name = 'LotCode' AND A.Value LIKE '001-000-A%'

-- XML
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Product
WHERE
  XmlAttributes.exist('/data[contains(LotCode,"001-000-A")]') = 1
```

**What I would do** ((of course only from my personal POV and experience)? If product is complex enough and I have resources to invest on it then I'd absolutely go with dynamically generated schema. Only serious disadvantage I saw is infrastructure development effort (and harder updates). 2nd best is Key/Value pair table(s). It has disadvantages but it's very easy to implement and pretty flexible.

Answer (score 0):

First, this doesn't really have anything to do with WPF.

As for the DB design, I would create a table of `CustomerAttributes`
with Id, AttributeName, and AttributeType (date, string, number, etc)

Then create a table of `ProductAttributes` with columns of ProductId, CustomerId, AttributeId and AttributeValue.

If you want the solution to be indexable, avoid XML.

Comment: You can index XML in Sql Server

Answer (score 0):

If you actually do use these values (Lot Number, Used By Date, Product Date) in your business logic (other than search/display and reports), then they should be added as a proper column to the table.

But if they are only used only for search/display or reports, I'd prefer using a vertical table (stockId,key,value), so that it would be more flexible, even you can go a bit far and use column per type as well such as (stockId,key,stringValue,DateValue,etc...) so you can optimize your queries without having to do casting or conversions.

1. Have separate fields in the stock table

This is simpler, but only supports up to 3 additional properties, and your search queries will be very complicated, having to determine which field is what from another mapping table, and same goes for reports.

2. Have single fields and just do a cast for non string values

Additional to the issues in the 1, you have to do dynamic casting also in your queries which is next to impossible to achieve using NHibernate.

3. Store these in a separate table all together

Does not have any advantage, unless it's a vertical table which is 5th point

4. XML data type

Probably not that easy to do searching using a query, however there are built-in functions for XML search in databases and if NHibernate supports it, than this one definitely worth considering.

5. Key/Pair value table

Best approach I can think of, in terms of searching, display as well as reporting.